# Get list of Granted Authorities for another user in Spring MVC/Security

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, spring-security, authorization

In Spring, there are many ways to obtain the granted authorities for the current session.  Like so:

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()`

Is there a way to obtain a list of granted authorities for **another user**?  I've checked out the [SessionRegistry](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html) object, and while this will get me a list of sessions and usernames, I don't believe I'll have access to any granted authority information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would do this through `UserDetailsService`. Inject `UserDetailsService` in the bean where you need it and call `loadUserByUsername` to obtain `UserDetails` object for a given username. `UserDetails` object has a method for accessing granted authorities (e.g. `getAuthorities()`).